# Find the solutions of $\log(z) = 4i$ in the form $(x + iy)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I was tring to complete the problem but ended up at:

$$\frac{1}{2} \ln(x^2 + y^2) + i \textrm{Arg}(x + iy) = 4i$$

Can  anyone help me out to solve this question?

Comment: I was tempted to change your $\ln$ to $\log$, since you have the latter in the title, but then decided that would be too much of an editorial imposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
z=r e^{i \theta}
\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad
\log z = \log r + i \theta
$$

$$
 \log r + i \theta = 4 i \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad r = 1, \, \theta = 4.
$$
Remembering $\log 1 = 0$. The final answer:

$$
z = e^{4i + 2k\pi}, \qquad k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

$$
e^{4i} = \cos 4 + i \sin 4
$$

Comment: how do we get r=1?

Comment: Just wondering how do we find 2kπ as seen from the power of exp and did u have any idea to change the answer in (x+iy) form? @dantopa

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue how to do this but here is  a GUESS.

log(z)=4i$

$z = e^{4i}$

$z =\cos(4)+i\sin(4)$

Comment: If you "have no clue how to do it", why answer then?